# Webpage will load external CSS and JS in Microsoft Edge but will not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

My project has me making a simple webpage with javascript functions to add, subtract, multiply, cube, and divide two numbers. I have an external CSS stylesheet Lab7.css and an external javascript file Lab7JS.js that will load and work fine when I use Microsoft Edge but will not work when I use Chrome. I am using Wampserver64 on my home computer.

Here is the code for the HTML portion of the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<html>
<head>
    <title>Lab7</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"   content="text/html;charset=UTF8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Lab7.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Lab7JS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<legend>
SIMPLE MATHEMATICS BOX:
</legend>
<form name="calcForm">
<br />

First Integer <input type="text" name="num1" size="15">
Second Integer <input type="text" name="num2" size="15">
ANSWER <input type="text" name="output" size="20" readonly>
<BR><BR> 
SELECT THE OPERATION TO PERFORM & CLICK ON THE APPROPRIATE BUTTON
<br />
<br>
<table width="95%">
<tr>
    <td  width="16%" align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="add()">
    <td  width="16%" align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Sub" onClick="sub()">
    <td  width="16%" align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Multiply" onClick="multiply()">
    <td  width="16%" align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Cube" onClick="cube()">
    <td  width="16%" align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Divide" onClick="divide()">
    <td align="right">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" alt="reset">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the css stylesheet:

```
form 
{
    background:#90EE90; 
    border: #0000CC double 4px; 
    width: 80%;
}
h2 
{
    color: #CC00FF; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
legend 
{ 
    color:blue; 
    font-size:+6;
}
```

Here is the code for the Javascript file:

```
function add()
{
    // Get values from form
    var num1, num2;
    num1 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num1.value);
    num2 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num2.value);

    // Compute the sum.
    var sum = num1+num2;

    // Display sum in form.
    document.calcForm.output.value = sum;
}

function sub()
{
    // Get values from form
    var num1, num2;
    num1 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num1.value);
    num2 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num2.value);

    // Compute the difference.
    var sum = num1-num2;

    // Display sum in form.
    document.calcForm.output.value = sum;
} 

function divide()
{
    // Get values from form
    var num1, num2;
    num1 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num1.value);
    num2 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num2.value);

    // Compute the quotient.
    var sum = num1/num2;

    // Display sum in form.
    document.calcForm.output.value = sum;
}
function multiply()
{
    // Get values from form
    var num1, num2;
    num1 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num1.value);
    num2 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num2.value);

    // Compute the product.
    var product = num1*num2;

    // Display product in form.
    document.calcForm.output.value = product;
}
function cube()
{
    // Get values from form
    var num1;
    num1 = parseInt(document.calcForm.num1.value);

    // Compute the product.
    var product = num1*num1*num1;

    // Display product in form.
    document.calcForm.output.value = product;
}
```

Comment: What's the error in console?

Comment: How are you verifying that the external files are "not loading"? Have you looked in the network log?

Comment: Why are you using HTML4 strict instead of HTML5?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token Lab7JS.js:1

Comment: I am just trying to edit the code my professor gave us to work with.

Comment: It is not styling the page via the CSS stylesheet and none of the functions are working when I use Chrome, but everything works fine when I use Edge.

Comment: The code have many problems. Eg `font-size:+6;` the value without a unit is invalid. That's not causing the error you've mentioned but just saying

Comment: Try changing your `!doctype` tag to: `<!DOCTYPE html>`, also inspect your page (right click ;)) and go to network tab to look for path errors.

Comment: Changing the doctype worked for the styling problem thank you!

Comment: I just tried this code on Chrome and it's working fine

Comment: This is what Chrome is showing in the sources tab when it does load the Lab7JS.js file. 畦据楴湯愠摤⤨਍ൻ †⼠ 敇⁴慶畬獥映潲⁭潦浲਍††慶⁲畮ㅭ‬畮㉭഻ †渠浵‱‽慰獲䥥瑮搨捯浵湥⹴慣捬潆浲渮浵⸱慶畬⥥഻ †渠浵′‽慰獲䥥瑮搨捯浵湥⹴慣捬潆浲渮浵⸲慶畬⥥഻ഊ †⼠ 潃灭瑵⁥桴⁥畳⹭਍††慶⁲畳⁭‽畮ㅭ渫浵㬲਍†਍††⼯䐠獩汰祡猠浵椠⁮潦浲മ †搠捯浵湥⹴慣捬潆浲漮瑵異⹴慶畬⁥‽畳㭭਍ൽഊ昊湵瑣潩⁮畳⡢ഩ笊਍††⼯䜠瑥瘠污敵⁳牦浯映牯൭ †瘠牡渠浵ⰱ渠浵㬲਍††畮ㅭ㴠瀠牡敳湉⡴潤畣敭瑮挮污䙣牯⹭畮ㅭ瘮污敵㬩਍††畮㉭㴠瀠牡敳湉⡴潤畣敭瑮挮污䙣牯⹭畮

Comment: Sagar V is there a setting or something on my end in Chrome that could cause it not to work?